# Error: Package: python-netifaces-0.10.4-1.el7.x86_64 (openstack-ocata) Requires: python(abi) = 2.7 when I install the `packstack`

Tags: linux, openstack, packstack

When I install the `packstack`:

```
sudo yum install -y openstack-packstack
```

I get the below errors:

```
Error: Package: python-netifaces-0.10.4-1.el7.x86_64 (openstack-ocata)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 (base)
               python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-ply-3.4-4.el7.noarch (openstack-ocata)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 (base)
               python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-1.el7.x86_64 (openstack-ocata)
           Requires: libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: puppet-4.6.2-2.el7.noarch (openstack-ocata)
           Requires: rubygem(json)
Error: Package: python-idna-2.0-1.el7.noarch (openstack-ocata)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 (base)
               python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: 1:hiera-1.3.4-5.el7.noarch (openstack-ocata)
           Requires: ruby(release)
.........
```

Comment: CentOS 6 : You cannot install a package meant for CentOS 7. Looks like you have some impossible file.repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/

Comment: @KnudLarsen you mean I can not `sudo yum install -y openstack-packstack` in CentOS 6.5 ?

Comment: Seems you have a repo file ( in /etc/yum/repos.d/ ) with an URL or a mirror list for **CentOS 7** . Not possible. Please delete or edit. .... Everything in /etc/yum/repos.d/ must be for CentOS 6 specificly !

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thank you , I use the Cent OS 7.2 install success.